# drupal 7: how to access list-field's key instead of its label (field api)

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

I'm working on a custom theme and googled the whole day but can't find an answer to my question:

how to print out a cck list field's key instead of its label?

I think it's the right way to access fields via the field api, right?
so I try

```
$output = field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_list');
print render($output);
```

that seems to be the way to get the label value of the key|label pair. but even if i set the display options format to 'key' - it only prints the label value. what am I doing wrong?

I know there are other options to render the key but how is it possible using field api?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the field value itself (which will be the allowed values array key) with [`field_get_items()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_get_items/7):

```
$items = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_list');
$key = $items[0]['value'];
```

If you need to match those up again at any point you can get the full key/value list from the field metadata:

```
$info = field_info_field('field_list');
$values = $info['settings']['allowed_values'];
$label = $values[$key];
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a similar way. This example works for a Country list with ISO codes.
The idea is to render the Name of the Country that was selected because the dump returns only the key ( iso code in this case)

Format of the select list on the backend:

```
AR|Argentina
US|United States
```

Assuming you have selected United States on the backend and you want to print the country name on the node template:

```
$country_field = field_info_field('field_country_iso');
$country_iso = $node->field_country_iso[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
$country_name = $country_field['settings']['allowed_values'][$country_iso];
```

then

```
print $country_name; // This will return United States, not US code
```

I hope this helps.